# Get ipython notebook filename in function

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

This code works fine in an Ipython/Juypter cell to get the notebook filename:

```
js = """var kernel = IPython.notebook.kernel;
var thename = window.document.getElementById("notebook_name").innerHTML;
var command = "theNotebook2 = " + "'"+thename+"'";
kernel.execute(command);"""
display(Javascript(js))
theNotebook2 + '.ipynb'

'techela.ipynb'
```

If I define a function in a cell and call it:

```
def get_filename():
    """Get the notebook filename."""
    js = """var kernel = IPython.notebook.kernel;
var thename = window.document.getElementById("notebook_name").innerHTML;
var command = "theNotebook2 = " + "'"+thename+"'";
kernel.execute(command);"""
    display(Javascript(js))
    return theNotebook2 + '.ipynb'

get_filename()

'techela.ipynb'
```

It also seems to work fine and give me the filename.

However, if I put that function in a module, and import it, then it stops working.

```
from techela import get_filename
get_filename()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-42ee37d0d253> in <module>()
      1 from techela import get_filename
----> 2 get_filename()

/Users/jkitchin/techela/ipynb/techela.py in get_filename()
     11 kernel.execute(command);"""
     12     display(Javascript(js))
---> 13     return theNotebook2 + '.ipynb'
     14 
     15 

NameError: name 'theNotebook2' is not defined
```

Any idea why this is failing?

Comment: I don't think it was ever fully working: I'd guess that you ran the code multiple times when it was in a cell. Displaying Javascript does not execute it synchronously, so you can't write a function that retrieves the filename and gives it back. The kernel won't process the code from the JS setting the name until after it finishes running the cell.